# Unlock 512 MB Ram Model B

Tags: memory

I want to unlock the 512 MB RAM on my Raspberry PI.
I have RASPMBC installed and followed http://hubcitylabs.org/unlocking-your-new-raspberry-pis-512mb-of-memory/

But it isnt working, I get error messages everytime I want to run the FW update

Comment: What error messages are you getting? We can't really help you without knowing what's wrong and what you've tried and where you are currently (what step you are working on). Please add that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using any recent version of Raspbian / RaspBMC will do it automatically. You don't need to do anything manually.

Comment: Ok, the menu is really laggy, thats why i thaught there s too less ram/gpu memory

Comment: That's normal for XBMC on the Pi. It doesn't have enough CPU grunt to scroll the menu smoothly

Comment: are there any mods to make it smooth?

Comment: You could try to overclock the Pi.

Comment: Ok, I ll try that